# C# : how to move single dimensional array into multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, unsafe

I have a single dimensional array:

```
double[] vals = new double[1e9];
vals = <random function call>
double[,] output = new double[1e3,1e6];
```

As our arrays are very very large (like billions). I want to somehow get the values from `vals` into `output` and return `output` without actually doing an explicit copy. In C++ this would just be a `reinterpret_cast` but C# doesn't work that way.

I tried using some unsafe pointer tricks but that doesn't seem to work:

```
public static unsafe TDest ReinterpretCast<TSource, TDest>(TSource source)
{
    var sourceRef = __makeref(source);
    var dest = default(TDest);
    var destRef = __makeref(dest);
    *(IntPtr*)&destRef = *(IntPtr*)&sourceRef;
    return __refvalue(destRef, TDest);
}
```

I am fully aware this is unsafe and probably a bad idea, but I need to do it anyways to finish my project. Is there anyway I could do this (if I don't care about safety?). I was thinking maybe Span or some other constructs I am unfamiliar would allow this to be done?

I tried to use span, reinterpret cast and changing our cpp api to do what I asked.

Comment: 1. Why do you assign vals if you reassign it from Function right after? 2. You can "fake" a 2D array by wrapping the 1D-Array and mapping coords. If you don't insist on an actual 2D-Array that is.

Comment: I don't actually assign it, that's just to give some information about the length, in production, the code is currently double[] vals = <function>

Comment: 1. What is the rule to translate [1e9] to [1e3,1e6]? 2. Do you need it to be an array or you just need an indexer?

Comment: The rule is simply take slices of size 1e3

Comment: [This](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#span-like-types-for-all-platforms) library (shameless self promotion) allows you to do this by the [`Array2D<T>`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Collections_Array2D_1.htm) type. See a live example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SA92Do).

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can't change the rank of an `Array` in C# because in memory, the array is stored as a full object including a method table pointer (pointing to the method table for `Array`), the number of components and then a table of the dimensions of the array followed by the raw data of the array.

So because a C# `Array` is a full object in memory, it isn't possible to re-interpret the data for a different rank.

See the comment above the source for [`RawArrayData`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.CoreCLR.cs,9cc1d4c1775aedc3).

Comment: A Jagged array would be fine too, is that possible? to create a jagged array where every single inner array is a memory pointer to vals (from my original question)? I just need this to do matrix operations on the array

Comment: wait if what you say is true, why is it not possible to try to reflect the internals of the multidimensional array into what I want? Is there some specific way I can overwrite the handle to the raw data and then just reflect the table dimensions?

Comment: If your solution is to start fiddling with .Net framework internals, you're already heading down the wrong path. Just use a span like a normal human being, you even have [`Span2D`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/high-performance/span2d) to make it look like a 2D array if indexing into a 1D array is too complicated (I mean it's a whole addition and multiplication, after all).

Comment: I'd love to, but this is basically library code (for internal use only) so that would require our users to learn to Span2D, which we *really* don't want. Having userland code touch unsafe bits like span2d is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @w13245 For the same reason - there is no handle to the raw data - there is a handle (pointer) to the full object, including all the dimensions immediately followed in memory by the raw data. You can't create a jagged array for the same reason - each member of the jagged array would be an array, which would mean it needs to be a full object with length and data consecutive in memory, which can't be the case for a row in the middle of a larger array. The best you could do is create your own class to represent a 2D view of the 1D array.

Comment: @w13245 What if you went about it the other way? Store your data in a 2D array and use your own (private internal) class to work with it as if it were a 1D array, and then return the 2D array?